# Cannot import android.text.util.Regex? Where is it?

Tags: android, regex, linkify

I'm developing an application and I want to use `android.text.util.Regex.WEB_URL_PATTERN` as the pattern for the `Linkify`. But, as I have notice, I cannot import `android.text.util.Regex` for some reason.

Why so? Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: FYI http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/package-summary.html ; no `Regex` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import it.

Check the src code and you will see you will have something like:

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
public class Regex {
```

Comment: It's that. Only the Linkify class can access this. I did not see the @hide directive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `android.text.util.Regex` in the SDK. Hence, it cannot be imported. I cannot even find it in the current Android source code, suggesting the class may have been removed in Android 2.2 (or earlier).

Here is the definition of `WEB_URL_PATTERN` from an earlier version of the source:

```
/**
 *  Regular expression pattern to match RFC 1738 URLs
 *  List accurate as of 2007/06/15.  List taken from:
 *  http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
 *  This pattern is auto-generated by //device/tools/make-iana-tld-pattern.py
 */
public static final Pattern WEB_URL_PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile(
        "((?:(http|https|Http|Https):\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)"
        + "\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_"
        + "\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\\@)?)?"
        + "((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}\\.)+"   // named host
        + "(?:"   // plus top level domain
        + "(?:aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])"
        + "|(?:biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz])"
        + "|(?:cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz])"
        + "|d[ejkmoz]"
        + "|(?:edu|e[cegrstu])"
        + "|f[ijkmor]"
        + "|(?:gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy])"
        + "|h[kmnrtu]"
        + "|(?:info|int|i[delmnoqrst])"
        + "|(?:jobs|j[emop])"
        + "|k[eghimnrwyz]"
        + "|l[abcikrstuvy]"
        + "|(?:mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])"
        + "|(?:name|net|n[acefgilopruz])"
        + "|(?:org|om)"
        + "|(?:pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy])"
        + "|qa"
        + "|r[eouw]"
        + "|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]"
        + "|(?:tel|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])"
        + "|u[agkmsyz]"
        + "|v[aceginu]"
        + "|w[fs]"
        + "|y[etu]"
        + "|z[amw]))"
        + "|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]" // or ip address
        + "[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]"
        + "|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]"
        + "[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}"
        + "|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])))"
        + "(?:\\:\\d{1,5})?)" // plus option port number
        + "(\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\;\\/\\?\\:\\@\\&\\=\\#\\~"  // plus option query params
        + "\\-\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\_])|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?"
        + "(?:\\b|$)"); // and finally, a word boundary or end of
                        // input.  This is to stop foo.sure from
                        // matching as foo.su
```